Copy framebuffer of 3D View into image
General Question: How can I copy the frame buffer of the currently active viewport to an image within Blender?
The following link already addressed the question, however it utilizes a modal operator that I don't really need. In my case, the script should be executed once and then an image of the currently active viewport should be created and if it already exists it should be overwritten.
Copy framebuffer of 3D View into custom frame buffer
But how could I achieve something like this? Any help is really appreciated and responses in the form of code lines are very welcome as well!
Thank you for your time and effort!

So like, Viewport Render?

yea basically an image of the active viewport without any overlays, gizmo and background colors

That’s Viewport Render. Like that’s a thing. See https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.render.html#bpy.ops.render.render

I tried this but it wont work in cycles and if the viewport is set to rendered view unfortunatly

Do you need it to be Cycles?

Yes it must be independend of the mode the user is using like in the frame buffer question I lonked above

Maybe try doing https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.camera_to_view and then rendering normally?
